# Retrieving value from between word and comma but includes delimiting word

Tags: javascript, regex

**SAMPLE TEXT**

Re: SURNAME, FOPENAME (01/01/1901)
9 SOME PLACE, SOME WHERE,, SOME ROAD, AREGION, AA1  1AA
DOCTOR A NONYMOUS
The above patient attended here on

This is the format we receive a section of text in. We've got many more regular expressions and I'm almost there. I'm using the following (javascript specific):

[/[^,]*(?:\n|\r)+DOCTOR/](https://regex101.com/r/kM0tH1/1)

The only problem is that it's giving me this string in return:

```
AA1  1AA
DOCTOR
```

I don't want the DOCTOR on the end. I've been fiddling moving it round, and trying different methods but they either highlight other different sections of the text or just fail. Anyone with a quick idea how to solve?

Comment: Maybe a lookahead solution [`[^,]*(?=[\n\r]+DOCTOR)`](https://regex101.com/r/oY5jS4/1) will do?

Comment: Hmm, I'd been so convinced it needed a reverse lookup I never even considered a standard lookahead. I'll test this out on the full body of text. Thanks! On first glance, it appears to still be fine, I'll have to test with a few more documents first though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match `AA1 1AA` before a newline sequence(s) followed with `DOCTOR`, you can use a regular positive lookahead `(?=[\r\n]+DOCTOR\b)`:

```
[^,]*(?=[\n\r]+DOCTOR\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY5jS4/2)

Lookaheads do not consume characters, so `DOCTOR` will not be part of the match. Note that the `\b` after `DOCTOR` forces a whole word match, remove if it is not expected. The newline sequences can be matches with a character class `[\r\n]` that is more efficient than alternation `(?:\n|\r)`.